# How to scroll option into view on opening autocomplete in Angular 8 - Editable dropdown

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I am trying to create a field where the behavior is similar to select but the input is editable. The requirement is 'The user should be able to select from options or type in a valid value'. The options are not filtered but instead should focus on matching value in the options. I am trying to create one using mat autocomplete but I am not able to fix the scroll part. How can I scroll the selected option into view when typing in or focusing on the field again after selection?

HTML

```
<div>
  <mat-form-field [appearance]="'outline'">
    <mat-label>Select color</mat-label>
    <input type="text" matInput [(ngModel)]="color" [matAutocomplete]="colorOptions">
    <i class="icon-caret-down select-arrow" matSuffix></i>
    <mat-hint>Select or type a color</mat-hint>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-autocomplete #colorOptions="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of colors; let i=index" [value]="option"
      [ngClass]="{'active-option': option == color}">
      {{option}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</div>
```

TS

```
public colors = ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Orange', 'White', 'Black', 'Purple', 'Grey', 'Brown'];
public color = '';
```

SCSS

```
.active-option {
  background-color: #f5f5f5 !important;
  font-weight: bold !important;
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vetnpq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok here we go....

Let start with a little [StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-caj2sl).

Note that you should also focus on the selected element when someone uses the keydown from the input, which I didn't implement as it is a bit beyond the scope of the question. Overall I would recommend using the default behaviour, but since you asked..

**The css**

In the html is a `div` you can recognise by its `role='listbox'`. This `div` contains the `mat-option` elements. When the `mat-option` elements don't fit in the `div` the div will add a scrollbar with `overflow: auto`. So we just have to set the `scrollTop` value on the div to scroll.

**How to get the element**

Get the `div` through a property of the autocomplete object called `panel`. In order to do that get the autocomplete object and reference it using `@ViewChild()`.

**Calculate the value to set on scrollTop**

To calculate the value, get the height of the `mat-option`. The default is 48, so you could just set that. You should be able to get the height from the `AUTOCOMPLETE_OPTION_HEIGHT`.

*Note: I wasn't able to get visible results from modifying this value. Maybe I did something wrong. Or there could be something going on why modifying this constant has no real effects. So I just set it to the default value of 48.*

To get the correct `scrollTop` value, calculate it by using the index of the matched element.

**Add the logic with a method call**

Call this logic with a method that detects a change in value on the input: `(input)='changed_input()`.

**Below my code**

*app.module.ts*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';
import { MatAutocompleteModule } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import {AUTOCOMPLETE_OPTION_HEIGHT} from '@angular/material/autocomplete';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ 
    BrowserModule, 
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [
    {provide: AUTOCOMPLETE_OPTION_HEIGHT, useValue: 48 }
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

*app.component.html*

```
<div [formGroup]="testForm">
  <mat-form-field [appearance]="'outline'">
    <mat-label>Select color</mat-label>
    <input type="text" matInput [(ngModel)]="color"
    (input)='changed_input()'formControlName="color" [matAutocomplete]="colorOptions">
    <i class="icon-caret-down select-arrow" matSuffix></i>
    <mat-hint>Select or type a color</mat-hint>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-autocomplete 
  #matAutocomplete #colorOptions="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of colors; let i=index" [value]="option">
      {{option}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</div>
```

*app.component.ts*

```
import { Component, VERSION, ViewChild, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import {AUTOCOMPLETE_OPTION_HEIGHT} from '@angular/material/autocomplete';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChild('matAutocomplete') matAutocomplete;
  color = '';
  colors = ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Orange', 'White', 'Black', 'Purple', 'Grey', 'Brown'];
  testForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    @Inject(AUTOCOMPLETE_OPTION_HEIGHT) public option_height: number
  ) {}
  ngOnInit(){
    this.testForm = new FormGroup({
      color: new FormControl('')
    })
  }
  public changed_input(): void {
    const color_index = this.colors.findIndex( color_option => {
      return color_option.toLowerCase() === this.color.toLowerCase();
    });
    if(color_index === -1 ) return;
    this.matAutocomplete.panel.nativeElement.scrollTop = this.option_height*color_index;
  }
}
```

**A final note**

This is all fun and giggles to play with, but seriously just use the default behaviour and save your future self some misery.

Comment: Thanks @RobMonhemius this worked. But I wanted the same behavior on reopening after selection also. For now I handled that using simple scroll. But I am still searching for a better way to do it. Here is the stackblitz link for what I have done till now. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-geh4zz

Comment: @Vna `<mat-form-field (opened)='changed_input()'>` may work for that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you want is to add the user typed option into the options of the mat-autocomplete. If I've got your point than try to take a look in the following StackBlitz edit of your code [edited-stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-28f5yc).

I've added a button and when user press the button, I'm adding the option to the list in the autocomplete. Also you can intercept when the user press "enter" and trigger the action that I've added to the button.

Here the edited code:

**HTML:**

```
   <div [formGroup]="testForm">
     <mat-form-field [appearance]="'outline'">
       <mat-label>Select color</mat-label>
       <input type="text" matInput formControlName="color" 
             [matAutocomplete]="colorOptions" [(ngModel)]="currentOption">
       <i class="icon-caret-down select-arrow" matSuffix></i>
       <mat-hint>Select or type a color</mat-hint>
     </mat-form-field>
     <mat-autocomplete #colorOptions="matAutocomplete">
       <mat-option *ngFor="let option of colors; let i=index" [value]="option"
         [ngClass]="{'active-option': option == testForm.controls.color.value}">
         {{option}}
       </mat-option>
     </mat-autocomplete>
     <button (click)="addOption()">+</button>
     {{currentOption}}
    </div>
```

**TS:**

```
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  color = '';
  colors = ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Orange', 'White', 'Black', 'Purple', 'Grey', 'Brown'];
  testForm: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit(){
    this.testForm = new FormGroup({
      color: new FormControl('')
    })
  }

  public currentOption: any;

  public addOption(): void {
    this.colors.push(this.currentOption);
  }
```

Let me know if I understood right or not.

Comment: This is slightly different from the requirement. If I type in Grey and its already present in the options it has to be scrolled into view.

Comment: Oks. I would let the correct answer to Rob Monhemius, meanwhile I've edited his stackblitz for scroll onto the selected option even when you reopening the mat-autocomplete options. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-74grpy I've added the click event on `mat-form-field` and not on `input` element because if you click within the border of the element `mat-form-field` if would not trigger the click element but it would open the options.

Answer (score 0):

to sync the panel scroll focus with the selected item and activated item
you can easily take advantage of `optionActivated` and `opened`  events on the `mat-autocomplete` element:

```
<mat-autocomplete 
(opened)="onPanelOpened()"
(optionActivated)="onOptionActivated($event)">

</mat-autocomplete>
```

in the component.ts implement the `onOptionActivated` method just for keydown and keyup focusing on activated element and also `onPanelOpened` method to focus on the first selected item after opening the panel:

```
 @ViewChild(MatAutocomplete) autoComplete!: MatAutocomplete;

 onPanelOpened() {
   const firstSelectedOption = this.autoComplete.options.find(o => o.selected);

   firstSelectedOption?._getHostElement()?.scrollIntoView({
     block: 'center',
   });
 }


onOptionActivated(event: MatAutocompleteActivatedEvent) {
   event.option?._getHostElement()?.scrollIntoView({
     block: 'end',
   });
 }
```